# Chromium, Tweetdeck, and Geany don't work when set to run at login

Tags: startup

I have "automatically remember running applications when logging out" enabled in "Startup Application Preferences". However, some programs don't work with this setting: namely Chromium  TweetDeck and Geany; none of these programs are restored whenever I restart the machine. Other programs such as Firefox, Gedit, Terminal are able to be restored automatically on restart.

Is there any way I can have ALL of these programs restored appropriately on startup? or at least Chromium?

Answer (score 2):

The only suggestion I can make is you just add start up entries for each of them (in system, prefs, start up applications) and file a bug.

This means they will always load up on login but that sounds desirable.

Comment: Yup, I have the same issue. Neither Twhirl nor Thunderbird starts when I log in. The only solution I've been able to come up with is to start them manually (or add them as start up entries)